# Django admin panel deletion order causing FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Tags: django, database, django-models, foreign-keys, django-admin

When I attempt to delete a user from the admin panel, I get an error screen saying `IntegrityError at /admin/auth/user/` `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed`, but at no point in the entire page does it mention any model, column, nor anything that could help me narrow it down. I assume it is due to my model which has a `models.OneToOneField(AuthUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE)`, though I would think the on_delete should delete it, it seems to end up dangling or something because if I delete the entry in that table first, and then delete the user that one referenced, they get deleted correctly without issue.

What do I have to do to make my entries delete themselves correctly upon deleting the user?

How do I read the error page correctly to know what's causing it?

How to override the admin delete to delete from the other table first before deleting the user normally?

Definition of my model.
[image]

Where I'm deleting the user to cause the error.
[image]

The error it gives me.
[image]

Where I have to delete the entry before deleting the user in order to avoid errors.
[image]

Comment: Please share model code instead of image.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) [mre] Saying you (re)searched is not helpful. Give relevant results. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097)

Comment: Re (re)search success: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: Ask 1 question. Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation.

Comment: Problem is I have no clue how to even get back to this point and the whole thing is quite big at this point. If there's no way to know the issue from that model definition, then the issue is bigger than I thought, and I've got no chance at fixing it. I'll stick to deleting in order and forget about it functioning correctly.
If anyone has any generic answers to IntegrityErrors or Foreign Key constraint failures, I'll try those, but I'm long past tired of this error and after rereading the entire error log and many posts about Foreign Key errors 1 to many times, I still have no clue the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I did some last random tests before dropping the issue and ignoring it, and I happened across the fact that replacing `AuthUser` with `User` fixes everything.

I've got no clue where `User` exists, because it is not an existing table in my database, like `AuthUser` is, but for some reason with that it all works just fine, so no complaints from me.